# SSIS - SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am new to SSIS and have worked earlier on DTS. Currently, I have a ASPX project that uses crystal reports to render some reports.

I am modeling data coming in various data sources into one sql server. As part of that, I have a complex excel file that needs to be mapped into SQL Server.

I am planning to Use SSIS. Now, I believe there is no SSIS project for VS2010.

Could somebody help me to get started? What environment do I need to set up for this? Where can I find the plug-in for visual studio?

I appreciate your support.

Comment: So I cannot just install BIDS correct? I am using SQL Server 2005 then I have to install Visual Studio 2005 and then install BIDS 2005 for visual studio 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SSIS packages are for SQL Server 2005, you need to use BIDS for Visual Studio 2005. If they are for SQL Server 2008, BIDS for Visual Studio 2008 and so on

Comment: So I am using SQL Server 2005 then I have to install VS2005 and then BIDS for VS2005?

Comment: not really, when you install SQL Server 2005, you can install SSIS and with the installation, BIDS 2005 will be installed. If you dont have VS 2005 I think it installs too (not sure here)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct Microsoft has not released an upgrade of BIDS for anything above VS 2008. However in order to create SSIS packages you have to use the version of VS that comes with the SQL Management tools. So SQL 2005 would have VS 2005 BIDS installed. As [Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10654425/847990) already mentioned.

The catch you might have if you already have VS 2010 installed on your computer, is installing a lesser version of VS tends to make things stop working in the higher version. So BIDS is going to install VS 2005 and it has a chance of messing up some of your VS2010 install. I have had different results when doing this but if it does happen you might just need to re-run the installation of VS2010 to repair anything that got messed up.

Answer (score 2):

[Business Intelligence Development Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Intelligence_Development_Studio)

is the only place you can edit SSIS with the visual studio IDE

Comment: Database Edition of Visual Studio cannot be used to create SSIS packages. BIDS would be what he is looking for.